# How can I overload = operator to copy by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

I know it may pointless questions but I just wonder it is possible to use = operator to copy by reference like that

```
int a, b=5;
a = b;
a = 4;
cout<<b<<endl;
```

In other words of what I am trying to do is to make this code print 4, instead of 5.
Thanks for any comments...

Comment: What's wrong with just using a normal reference?

Comment: This is what C++ references are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this because you have already declared `a` as an `int`.

Either make `a` a reference (`int&`) or a pointer (`int*`) to `b`.

Comment: He can't do that via overloading the = operator

Answer (score 4):

It might be possible for custom classes using some obscure tricks, but in general it's a no-go. One of the most important rules for operator overloading: Don't ever change the meaning of operators. E.g. don't swap the meaning of `+` and `-`. Sure, it could be done, but it will confuse others and probably yourself as well, reading the code a bit later.

What you're trying to do can be done in C++ using either pointers or references:

```
int b = 5;
int &a = b;
a = 4;
cout << b << endl; // prints 4
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do it. To overload assignment  without using a user-defined class.. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.10